# Using custom fonts in TinyMCE API for editor in django admin

Tags: django, fonts, django-admin, tinymce, django-tinymce

I am trying to use `TinyMCE` API in Django admin for blog post editing.

It is working flawlessly. However, now I want to add custom fonts to my editor.

As per `tinymce`

[documentation](https://www.tiny.cloud/blog/tinymce-custom-font-family/)

for adding custom fonts I have followed all steps but still cannot figure out what is wrong.

**Step-1: Add fonts as per menu option**

admin/base.html:

```
font_formats:"Andale Mono=andale mono,times; ........ ; Montserrat = Montserrat , sans-serif",`
```

**Step-2: Import fonts in tinymce**

admin/base.html:

```
{% extends "admin/base.html" %}
{% load static %}
{% block footer %}
        tinymce.init({
        ....
        content_css: "{% static "TinyMCE/style.css" %}",
        content_style:"@importurl('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2family=Montserrat:ital,wght@0,400;0,600;1,400&display=swap');",
        ....
{% endblock %}
```

TinyMCE/style.css

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2family=Montserrat:ital,wght@0,400;0,600;1,400&display=swap');
```

snapshot:

[image: the custom font is added in the dropdown menu 'Monstserrat']

**Step3: Import the font on the page**

admin/base.html

```
{% block extrahead %}
<style>
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:ital,wght@0,400;0,600;1,400&display=swap');
* {font-family : 'Montserrat', sans-serif;}
</style>
{% endblock %}
```

snapshot:

[image: the custom font changes in dropdown from fallback font to 'Monstserrat']

**Step4: Import the font on any published pages**
I am using tailwind in my project and my default font is `Monstserrat` which is perfectly working over the site

style.css

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:ital,wght@0,400;0,600;1,400&display=swap');
body{
    font-family: Montserrat, sans-serif;
}
```

**Problem:**

- Although I see the custom font 'Montserrat' in the dropdown on `tincymce` editor but when I select it falls back to sans-serf.

You can see the snippet here:

[image: you can see the snippet here]

Please note that I am not using `django-tinymce` package rather `tinymce` API.

Answer (score 0):

**Step-1:**

Remove space between fonts

```
Montserrat=Montserrat,sans-serif
```

This is because `font-family: 'Montserrat'` would render correctly and not render with a space `font-family: ' Montserrat'`. In case of space the font will not load on the browser.

**Step-2:**

We dont have to specify `content_style` once we have specified `content_css`. In some cases it might be useful but there is no point to add both in this case. Plus do add a `{% load static %}` tag before your script

```
{% extends "admin/base.html" %}
{% load static %}
{% block footer %}
        {{ block.super }}
        
        {% load static %}
        <script>
        tinymce.init({
        ....
        content_css: '{% static "TinyMCE/style.css" %}',
        ....
{% endblock %}
```

My problem is solved. Let me know if you have any questions.